# how to do HTML5 media queries

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML5 ,Can anybody tell me how to do responsive website.Just now I heard word media query which is related to make website responsive.Please help me out I dont know where to start in HTML5 and for responsive Website too.Please let me know if any tutorial website start  down from the scratch step by step is very useful for me.

Thank you,

Comment: First misconception : you do media queries with CSS. Second : Stackoverflow isn't a place to get tutorials or links to tutorials. You have a search engine for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a quick and easy example of how to do a responsive web in three steps 
[Responsive design in three steps](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

### [Getting started with media Queries](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2012/05/22/getting-started-with-css-media-queries.aspx)

Some other helpful links

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html

though you could have goggled it yourself

Comment: Yes, i did but I dont know how to do make my website responsive.